# Unable to access super query column in subquery inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to write following query. Have one problem in this query.

```
SELECT
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'Const_Id',
          `Constituencies`.`Const_Id`,
          'Const_name',
          CONVERT(`Constituencies`.`Const_name` USING utf8),
          'event_count',
          (
            SELECT
            COUNT(`events`.`event_id`)
            FROM
            `events`
            INNER JOIN `cons_circles_list` ON
            `cons_circles_list`.`cons_id` = `Constituencies`.`Const_Id` AND
            `cons_circles_list`.`active` = 1 AND
            `cons_circles_list`.`deleted` = 0
            WHERE `events`.`cons_circle_id` = `cons_circles_list`.`cons_circle_id` AND
            `events`.`deleted` = 0
          )
        ) as data FROM
        `Constituencies`
        WHERE
        `Constituencies`.`deleted` = 0
```

following line is have problem

`cons_circles_list`.`cons_id` = `Constituencies`.`Const_Id`

It's showing Unknown column `Constituencies`.`Const_Id` in 'on clause'

Please suggest any other methods.

Comment: Before giving downvote. Please put comment why?

Comment: Your query seems  not clear  to  me ..  please updated  your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Obviously ..  the inner query can't see the outer ..  but as suggetested  before  ..  update your question and add a sample and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the 'cons_circles_list'.'cons_id' = 'Constituencies'.'Const_Id' in inner join of 'events' and 'cons_circles_list'.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to rewrite the query in this manner:

```
SELECT
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'Const_Id', Const_Id,
          'Const_name', CONVERT(Const_name USING utf8),
          'event_count', event_count
          ) as data FROM(
            SELECT
            `Constituencies`.`Const_Id` Const_Id, 
            `Constituencies`.`Const_name` Const_name,
            COUNT(`events`.`event_id`) event_count
            FROM
            'events`
            INNER JOIN `cons_circles_list` ON
            `events`.`cons_circle_id` = `cons_circles_list`.`cons_circle_id` 
            INNER JOIN `Constituencies` ON `cons_circles_list`.`cons_id` = `Constituencies`.`Const_Id`
            WHERE `events`.`deleted` = 0  AND
            `cons_circles_list`.`active` = 1 AND
            `cons_circles_list`.`deleted` = 0 AND
            `Constituencies`.`deleted` = 0
            GROUP BY `Constituencies`.`Const_Id`, `Constituencies`.`Const_name`
          )q
```